# How to handle label size and location in the GUI form using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, user-interface, label, size

I create a simple GUI. I want to execute the GUI in any resolution screen. In my work screen, it show picture 1. Once I execute it in other screen, the size label, position is different, showed in the picture 2.
Anyone can help me please how to handle this? Thank you so much.

Picture 1
[image]

Picture 2
[image]

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize                 = '400,400'
$Form.text                       = "Form"
$Form.TopMost                    = $false
$form.AutoScale                  = $true
$form.AutoScaleMode              = "Font"
$Form.FormBorderStyle            = "FixedDialog"

$Groupbox1                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Groupbox
$Groupbox1.height                = 362
$Groupbox1.width                 = 367
$Groupbox1.text                  = "Group Box"
$Groupbox1.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15,21)

$Label1                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label1.text                     = "Do you need handling the job?"
$Label1.AutoSize                 = $true
$Label1.width                    = 25
$Label1.height                   = 10
$Label1.location                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(92,82)
$Label1.Font                     = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Button1                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button1.text                    = "Yes"
$Button1.width                   = 60
$Button1.height                  = 30
$Button1.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(34,263)
$Button1.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Button2                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button2.text                    = "No"
$Button2.width                   = 60
$Button2.height                  = 30
$Button2.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(268,263)
$Button2.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Form.controls.AddRange(@($Groupbox1))
$Groupbox1.controls.AddRange(@($Label1,$Button1,$Button2))


[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

#### updated

I try this

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.FormBorderStyle = "FixedDialog"
$Width = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens.bounds.width
$Heigt = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens.bounds.height

$Widht_Form = $Width[0] / 3.5
Write-Host "$Widht_Form"
$Heigt_Form = $Heigt[0] / 1.8
Write-Host "$Heigt_Form"
$Form.Width = $Widht_Form
$Form.Height = $Heigt_Form

$label1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'
$Yes = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
$No = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
$Title = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'
$timer1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Timer'
$InitialFormWindowState = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState'

$Form_Load = {  
    $TotalTime = 10 #in seconds
        $script:StartTime = (Get-Date).AddSeconds($TotalTime)
        #Start the timer
        $timer1.Start()
}   
$Cancel_Click={ 
}
$timer1_Tick={
        #Use Get-Date for Time Accuracy
        [TimeSpan]$span = $script:StartTime - (Get-Date)
        #Update the display
        $Form.Text = $label1.Text = "{0:N0}" -f $span.TotalSeconds
        if ($span.TotalSeconds -le 0) {
            $timer1.Stop()
            $Form.Close()
        }
    }

$Form_StateCorrection_Load=
{
    $Form.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
}

$Form_Cleanup_FormClosed=
{
    try
    {
        # $Cancel.remove_Click($Cancel_Click)
        $Form.remove_Load($Form_Load)
        $timer1.remove_Tick($timer1_Tick)
        $Form.remove_Load($Form_StateCorrection_Load)
        $Form.remove_FormClosed($Form_Cleanup_FormClosed)
    }
    catch [Exception]
    { }
}

$Form.SuspendLayout()
$Form.Controls.Add($label1)
$Form.Controls.Add($Yes)
$Form.Controls.Add($No)
$Form.Controls.Add($Title)

$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$Form.BackColor = "#f6f6f6"
$Form.add_Load($Form_Load)

$label1.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,20,style=Bold'
$Label1.ForeColor = "#176faa"
$label1.AutoSize = $true
$label1.width = 25
$label1.height = 10
$label1_height = $Heigt_Form / 2.5
$label1_width = $Widht_Form / 2.2
$label1.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($label1_width,$label1_height)

$Title.Text = "Do you need handling the job?"
$Title.ForeColor = "#176faa"
$Title.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,16,style=Bold'
$Title.AutoSize = $true
$Title.width = 25
$Title.height = 10
$Title_height = $Heigt_Form / 5
$Title_width = $Widht_Form / 5
$Title.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($Title_width,$Title_height)

$Yes.AutoSize = $true
$Yes_height = $Heigt_Form * 0.7
$Yes_width = $Widht_Form / 8
$Yes.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($Yes_width,$Yes_height)
$Yes.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(90,35)
$Yes.Text = "Yes"
$Yes.Add_Click(
    {
    Write-Host "Call GUI Control"
    Start-Sleep -s 1
    $Form.Close()
    }
)

$No.AutoSize = $true
$No_height = $Heigt_Form * 0.7
$No_width = ($Yes_width * 6) - 35
$No.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($No_width,$No_height)
$No.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(90,35)
# $No.BackColor = "#9fd5f3"
$No.Text = "No"
$No.Add_Click(
    {
    Write-Host "Continue the process"
    $Form.Close()
    }
)

$timer1.add_Tick($timer1_Tick)
$Form.ResumeLayout()

#Save the initial state of the form
$InitialFormWindowState = $Form.WindowState
#Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
$Form.add_Load($Form_StateCorrection_Load)
#Clean up the control events
$Form.add_FormClosed($Form_Cleanup_FormClosed)
#Show the Form
return $Form.ShowDialog()
```

This way alson mesh up the label and button once execute in the different screen

Comment: I would try to work with % of current screen size.. `$screenSize = [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::VirtualScreen`. With this you can get `$width = $screen.Size.Width` and `$height = $screen.Size.Height`. Then I would change all sizes from your form to i.e : `$form.ClientSize=$height/10,$width/10` and same with height, width, and location.. I haven't tested this solution, it should give you just an idea

Comment: Correct syntax would be `$Form.ClientSize = "$($height/2),$($width/5)"`

Comment: hi @DanStef it return this error Exception setting "ClientSize": "Cannot convert value "117.5,384" to type "System.Drawing.Size". Error: "117.5 is not a valid value for Int32.""

Comment: 117.5 is not an Int32 ;-) . Try to `[int]$height=`

Answer (score 0):

You could use WMI Object for adjusting your objects in this form.
WMI objects returns key value information about your system.

This is how you can create the GUI that its objects' depends on the size of the screen:

```bsh
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$sw = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DesktopMonitor).ScreenWidth[1]
$sh = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DesktopMonitor).ScreenHeight[1]

$Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize                 = "$($sw / 2),$($sh / 2)"
$Form.text                       = "Form"
$Form.TopMost                    = $false
$form.AutoScale                  = $true
$form.AutoScaleMode              = "Font"
$Form.FormBorderStyle            = "FixedDialog"

$Groupbox1                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Groupbox
$Groupbox1.height                = $($sw / 2)
$Groupbox1.width                 = $($sh / 2)
$Groupbox1.text                  = "Group Box"
$Groupbox1.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15,21)

$Label1                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label1.text                     = "Do you need handling the job?"
$Label1.AutoSize                 = $true
$Label1.width                    = 25
$Label1.height                   = 10
$Label1.location                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($($sw / 16),$($sh / 12))
$Label1.Font                     = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Button1                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button1.text                    = "Yes"
$Button1.width                   = 60
$Button1.height                  = 30
$Button1.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($($sw / 20),$($sh / 3))
$Button1.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Button2                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button2.text                    = "No"
$Button2.width                   = 60
$Button2.height                  = 30
$Button2.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($($sw / 6),$($sh / 3))
$Button2.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Form.controls.AddRange(@($Groupbox1))
$Groupbox1.controls.AddRange(@($Label1,$Button1,$Button2))


[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: That's exactly what I though in my comment.. If I run your script, I don't get values for `$sw` and `$sh`.. It works only if I use `$screenSize = [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::VirtualScreen; $sw = $screen.Size.Width ; $sh = $screen.Size.Height;`

Comment: hi @Jim it return this error Cannot index into a null array. $sw = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DesktopMonitor).ScreenWidth[1]

Comment: I think it depends on the OS version of windows you use.
Try it without the [1] at the end and debug this line of code